# How to cast with TakeWhile

Tags: c#, parsing, casting

I have a string with numbers inside of it, I want to take the first of those numbers out into a double. (e.g. `"abc1.23,efg4.56"` => `1.23`)

What I am currently doing is this:

```
static double trimPriceResponse(string trimString)
    {
        double resultantDouble = new double();
        if (trimString.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToString().Length != 0)
        {
            resultantDouble = Double.Parse(String.Join("", Convert.ToChar(trimString.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit))));
        }
        else
        {
            trimString.Remove(0, 1);
            trimPriceResponse(trimString);
        }
        return resultantDouble;
    }
```

My issue is that when I do that I receive this runtime error: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'd__247`1[System.Char]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

I have tried casting to a string previously with this:

```
trimString.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToString().Length
```

But it returned an error stating that the string was in the incorrect format.

Is there a better way to get the double from the string or a way to make the above work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That won't give you what you want, it'll just print the type of whatever internal iterator class `TakeWhile` is implemented to return:

```
trimString.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToString()
```

`TakeWhile` returns an `IEnumerable<char>`, i.e. a sequence of characters. To get a string out of them, you have to concatenate those chars:

```
string.Concat(trimString.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit));
```

But also, the above will give you an empty string with the input `"abc1.23,efg4.56"`. That's because it'll take characters *while they're digits*, and the string starts with a letter, so it'll stop immediately. You'll first have to skip non digits, and *then* taking digits:

```
string.Concat(trimString.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit));
```

But even then that's not ideal, because your numbers are floats, not integers, so they have decimal separators:

```
string.Concat(trimString.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.'));
```

But then not any jumble of digits and periods is a valid number. Gah!
This is getting unwieldy.

Since what you're really trying to do is find a pattern (one or more digits, optionally followed by a period and then one or more digits) in text, I recommend you just use a regex, because this is their purpose. Then, since regex matches are still text, you have to parse them, but at least you're guaranteed for the parsing to succeed (assuming you use an invariant culture to ensure the decimal separator *is* a period).

```
var match = Regex.Match(trimString, @"\d+(\.\d+)?");
if(match.Success)
{
   resultantDouble = double.Parse(match.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

---

By the way, there's a code smell in there:

```
trimString.Remove(0, 1);
trimPriceResponse(trimString);
```

C# strings are immutable, `trimString.Remove(0, 1)` doesn't actually modify `trimString`, it returns a new string with the first character removed, so that whole line has no effect because you're not using the return value of `Remove`. You probably meant this:

```
trimPriceResponse(trimString.Remove(0, 1));
```